# Make/Load JSON of a custom class as if it is a variable

Tags: c#, json, class, serialization, deserialization

I would like my custom class to behave as a (string)variable when I make a JSON string of it via Newtonsoft serialize.

F.e.

```
public class YearMonth
{
    public YearMonth(int year, int month) {
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public YearMonth(string yearMonth) {
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public YearMonth startYearMonth { get; set; }
}

var data = new Data() { startYearMonth = new YearMonth(2021, 1) };
```

JSON of data should be:

```
{ startYearMonth = "202101" }
```

How should I realize this ?

I already have the deserialization working via the [JsonConstructor] attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write custom converters for JSON serialization (marshalling) in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Comment: Your json shows the value of `startYearMonth` as a string... not an object

Comment: Please specify in your question which json serializer are you using, like: Newtonsoft, System.Text.Json or other.

Comment: @Jawad: that what I want it to be in the JSON-string

Comment: What is your current question? How to serialize it?

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes, in the way I stated it ... so as if variable startYearMonth is a string variable instead of a YearMonth object. By default all the public variables inside the YearMonth will be serialized, but I want just one (string)value.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is by implementing a custom `JsonConverter<T>`

```cs
public class SimpleRepresentationConverter : JsonConverter<YearMonth>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, YearMonth value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());

    public override YearMonth ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, YearMonth existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => new YearMonth((string) reader.Value);
}
```

Here we are relying on that the `ToString` has been overwritten to print out data in the desired format.

I've extended your `YearMonth` class with that:

```cs
public class YearMonth
{
    public int Year { get; }
    public int Month { get; }
    public YearMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        Year = year;
        Month = month;
    }

    private YearMonth(string year, string month)
        :this(Convert.ToInt32(year), Convert.ToInt32(month))
    { }

    public YearMonth(string yearMonth)
        :this(yearMonth.Substring(0,4), yearMonth.Substring(4, 2))
    { }

    public override string ToString() => $"{this.Year}{this.Month:D2}";
}
```

- I've added some extra members as well to be able to test it easily
- Please bear in mind that this implementation is really fragile, because it breaks when it receives a malformed input.

Please also note that there is no need for the `JsonConstructor` attribute.

Rather we decorate the `startYearMonth` property of `Data` class:

```cs
public class Data
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SimpleRepresentationConverter))]
    public YearMonth startYearMonth { get; set; }
}
```

---

Usage

```cs
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Data() { startYearMonth = new YearMonth(2021, 02)}));
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>("{\"startYearMonth\":\"202102\"}")?.startYearMonth?.Month);
```